# How to modify some elements of a list using linq in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have this class:

```
public class Document
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool Checked {get;set; }
}
```

I create a set of 10 elements using `Enumerable.Repeat` static method:

```
var list = Enumerable.Repeat<Document>(
            new Document
            {
                ID="1",
                Type ="someType"
                Checked = true
            }, 10).ToList<Document>();
```

These creates 10 `Documents` all with the same properties. I need that some of them, for instance, the first 5 elements of the list `list` have the `Checked` property to `false`.

How can I achieve it, using as possible `linq`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternate idea to accomplish what you're asking for *(also populates your ID column with something other than "1")*:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                     .Select(i => new Document
                     {
                         ID = i.ToString(),
                         Type = "someType",
                         Checked = (i > 5)
                     }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that your original sample has a bug because it's creating a 10 element `List<Document>` that only has 1 actual `Document` object.  Here is a better way of doing it

```
Enumerable
  .Range(1, 10)
  .Select(i => 
    new Document() { 
      ID = "1",
      Type = "someType",
      Checked = i <= 5
    })
  .ToList();
```

*EDIT*

Changed the code to be simpler.  My original response was to editing an already existing list for which the following can be done

```
list.Take(5).ForEach(x => { x.Checked = false });
```

Note that you may have to define a simple `ForEach` method for this operation.  If you don't have one defined here is an example

```
static class Extensions { 
  internal static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e, Action<T> action) {
    foreach (var item in e) { 
      action(item); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where and how do I put this extension method?

Comment: @anmarti if you don't already have an extension method type in your project I would just add one.  I'll update my sample.  This just needs to be in the same namespace, or an imported one, from where you are writing that code

Comment: You should also note that when using Linq, the general assumption is that queries are chainable because they return a new list rather than modifying the original, and use of such a ForEach is, therefore, bad practice. It's still fairly common though.

Comment: For the curious about [ForEach](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) ...